# Pull only certain properties from each object in an array, and add to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, array.prototype.map

Attempting to learn javascript. I am trying to create Table Row data from data in state (being sent to components via Context API):

```
myArr = [
   {id: 1, name: AA, desc: DescA, color: red},
   {id: 2, name: BB, desc: DescB, color: orange},
   {id: 3, name: CC, desc: DescC, color: green},
   {id: 4, name: DD, desc: DescD, color: blue},
]
```

I would like to pull only name and color from each object, and create a new arr of objects.

```
newArr = [
   {name: AA, color: red}
   {name: BB, color: orange}
   {name: CC, color: green}
   {name: DD, color: blue}
]
```

I would like to do this to match my table data to table headers:

```
const headCells = [
    { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Name' },
    { id: 'color', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Color' },
];
```

I have tried `.map` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`, but I am using them incorrectly:

```
var newArray = activities.map(function(item) {return item["name", "color"]; })
```

Apologies for this almost certainly being a duplicate. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how do you go from `desc` to `color`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Oops - edited! Thanks

Comment: `.map` is the right approach, your syntax is just slightly wrong. `return { name: item.name, color: item.color }`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) to create a new array:

```js
const newArray = myArray.map(item => ({ name: item.name, color: item.color }));
```

Or, with destructuring assignement (ES6):

```js
const newArray = myArray.map(({ item, color }) => ({ item, color }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to get the `id` from `headCells`, you could get the keys in advance and map the properties.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'AA', desc: 'DescA', color: 'red' }, { id: 2, name: 'BB', desc: 'DescB', color: 'orange' }, { id: 3, name: 'CC', desc: 'DescC', color: 'green' }, { id: 4, name: 'DD', desc: 'DescD', color: 'blue' }],
    headCells = [{ id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Name' }, { id: 'color', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Description' }],
    keys = headCells.map(({ id }) => id),
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] }))));

console.log(result);
```

Approach with newer [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'AA', desc: 'DescA', color: 'red' }, { id: 2, name: 'BB', desc: 'DescB', color: 'orange' }, { id: 3, name: 'CC', desc: 'DescC', color: 'green' }, { id: 4, name: 'DD', desc: 'DescD', color: 'blue' }],
    headCells = [{ id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Name' }, { id: 'color', numeric: false, disablePadding: false, label: 'Description' }],
    keys = headCells.map(({ id }) => id),
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, o[k]])));

console.log(result);
```